State Management and Routes throwing error
I'm developing an app using Expo, Expo Router, and Zustand. I run into this problem where logging out often causes issues with screens that remain mounted in the background. These screens expect state or data that becomes invalid after the logout action, leading to errors.
Example:
A user logs in and navigates through screens A → B → C, then logs out leading them back to screen A. Since the screens B, and C remain in the background but still depend on the previous state, which is now cleared due to the logout. This causes errors as those screens aren’t designed to handle the state change.
What's a general approach to solve this? One way I clean think of is that I clear all routes in stack navigator and clear all zustand stores? But this approach is not scalable because every time I add a screen/route or add a new store I need to make sure I'm also clearing them. Is there a standard pattern to address this issue at scale?
